# Capybara: get selected radio button using webkit or poltergeist

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit, poltergeist

It's easy enough to get the selected radio button with Capybara using the `rack_test` driver.

```
# with rack_test
page.set('input_id')
# => "checked"
page.find('[checked]')
# => #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="input" path="/html/body/p[1]/label[1]/input">
```

However, this doesn't work with webkit or poltergeist.

```
# with webkit or poltergeist
page.set('input_id')
# => ""
page.find('[checked]')
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "[checked]"
```

I've also tried using the `#selected?` method, but it doesn't seem to be working for the radio button.

```
# with any driver
page.set('input_id')
page.all('input').select(&:selected?)
# => []
```

How can I get the checked radio button with Capybara in webkit or poltergeist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the difference between attributes and properties in JS supporting browsers. What you've done in rack-test works because it only knows about attributes. To find a checked input in the other browsers you could do

```
find('input:checked')
```

or you could do things like

```
find(:checkbox, 'input_id', checked: true)
find(:radio_button, 'input_id', checked: true)
find(:field, 'input_id', type: 'checkbox', checked: true)
```

etc...

Comment: That was it. Thank you!